# How can I execute WinSCP through run or windows key +R

Tags: command-line, operating-system, winscp

This might be a a lame question, but I seriously want to know how can I start WinSCP straight from *Run* dialog.

I have done the `PATH` variable setting and after doing this a DOS program starts as WinSCP. I'm guessing this is `winscp.com`. I want to run `WinSCP.exe`. I can do the whole `C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe`, but I just want to type WinSCP and the GUI should pop-up. Has anybody done this before?

Comment: Whoever is closing please let me know which is the right place to ask this

Answer (score 2):

If you set the path variable, typing WinSCP.exe should bring up the GUI. For future reference, questions like this would be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about Super User. I've tried what you've mentioned here but it didn't work. I shall go back and try again.

Comment: No problem. When I get some time I can take a look and try and figure this out again too.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify just filename without an extension, the `.com` has a precedence over `.exe` in Windows. And that's exactly a reason, why WinSCP command-line interface has `.com` extension. As it is expected, that when you run WinSCP from command-line, you want a command-line interface.

Apparently it's not your case. One solution is simply to delete `winscp.com` (or move it away from path), if you are not using it. You do not need it for WinSCP GUI to work.